# How to avoid pending promises when sending data from google api to discord.js?

Tags: node.js, google-api, discord.js, google-api-js-client

I am working on a Discord bot which could extract datas from an Excel sheet. For example when I will ask the bot : "!adress paul", I would like the bot to look for "paul" value in the column A of a sheet and return the value of the column B (of the row where the value Paul is) in the discord app.

So far, I succeeded to read data from the Excel sheet and report the datas in the console.log (when I call the console.log inside the function). However each time I call the value out of the function I have a 'Promise {}' that appears... I made many many research on the web, without finding the solution.

```
const discord = require('discord.js');
const {google} = require('googleapis');
const keys = require('./identifiants.json');


// Creation of the Spreadsheet client
const client1 = new google.auth.JWT(keys.client_email, null, 
keys.private_key, ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/spreadsheets']);

client1.authorize(function(err, tokens)
{   
    if(err)
    {
        console.log(err);
        return;
    } 
    else
    {
        console.log('Connected to Google Sheets');
    }   
});

// Creation of the Discrod client
const client2 = new discord.Client();

client2.on('ready', () => 
{
    console.log('Connected to Discord');
});

// Create an event listener for messages
client2.on('message', message => 
{
    if (message.content === '!address') 
    { 
        console.log("OK 1");

        let paul = address(client1);
        console.log(paul);
        console.log("OK2");
    }
});

async function address(client)
{   
    const gsapi = google.sheets({version:'v4',auth: client });
    const opt1 = {spreadsheetId: 'ID OF MY SPREADSHEET', range: 'Sheet1!A1:B3'};

    let data = await gsapi.spreadsheets.values.get(opt1);
    return data.data.values;
}

client2.login("MY CLIENT LOGIN")
```

In the console the message "Promise {pending}" appears between "OK1" and "OK2". Can someone help me on that case please? I would be very grateful

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `address` function is an **async** function so it will return a promise.

Therefore, you will need to use `then` to get the value:

```
client2.on('message', message => {
  if (message.content === '!address') { 

    address(client1)
      .then(paul => {
        console.log(paul);
      });

  }
});
```

Alternatively, you could use **async-await**:

```
client2.on('message', async (message) => {
  if (message.content === '!address') { 

    let paul = await address(client1);
    console.log(paul);

  }
});
```