# Calling multiple times the node google custom search API

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous, google-search-api

Using [this code](https://github.com/googleapis/google-api-nodejs-client/blob/master/samples/customsearch/customsearch.js) as a reference I tried making a function which takes words as input and chops it into 32-word pieces and returns a list of the different search data:

```js
async function singleSearch(q, cx, auth) {
   const res = await customsearch.cse.list({
     cx: cx,
     q: q,
     auth: auth,
   });
   return res.data;
 };

function search(words, apikey=process.argv[2], engineid=process.argv[3]){
   const limit = 32; //32 word limit on google search
   var searchQueries = [];
   var len = Math.ceil(words.length/limit);
   for(var i = 0; i < len; i++){
       searchQueries.push( words.slice(i*limit, (i+1)*limit).join(" ") )
   };
   var searches = []
   for(var i = 0; i < searchQueries.length; i++){
       searches.push(singleSearch(searchQueries[i], engineid, apikey).catch(console.error))
   };
   return searches
   }

a = search("Do I understand it correctly that anotherCall() will be called only when someCall() is completed? What is the most elegant way of calling them in parallel?".split(" "));
console.log(a)
```

This approach doesn't work and returns a `Promise { <pending> }`, and no matter how many `await/async`'s or `Promise.all()`'s I try, I can't get it to work. What is the correct way to call the API in this case?

Expected Output:

```
[
    {
  kind: 'customsearch#search',
  url: {
    type: 'application/json',
    template: 'https://www.googleapis.com/customsearch/v1?q={searchTerms}&num={count?}&start={startIndex?}&lr={language?}&safe={safe?}&cx={cx?}&sort={sort?}&filter={filter?}&gl={gl?}&cr={cr?}&googlehost={googleHost?}&c2coff={disableCnTwTranslation?}&hq={hq?}&hl={hl?}&siteSearch={siteSearch?}&siteSearchFilter={siteSearchFilter?}&exactTerms={exactTerms?}&excludeTerms={excludeTerms?}&linkSite={linkSite?}&orTerms={orTerms?}&relatedSite={relatedSite?}&dateRestrict={dateRestrict?}&lowRange={lowRange?}&highRange={highRange?}&searchType={searchType}&fileType={fileType?}&rights={rights?}&imgSize={imgSize?}&imgType={imgType?}&imgColorType={imgColorType?}&imgDominantColor={imgDominantColor?}&alt=json'},
    ...
 },
...
]
```

Comment: I wanted to inquire if you're interested in doing some work, I found one of your repos online (hookjs) and I was wondering if you'd be interested in getting in contact, if so, reply to the issue I opened there, thanks! Hope this doesn't appear as spam, I just didn't know how else to try to contact you since there isn't an email and your website is down.

Answer (score 1):

Since the `singleSearch` async function returns a promise, you need to use `then` to get the result of the search and then push it to the `searches` array.

```
searches.push(singleSearch(searchQueries[i], engineid, apikey).catch(console.error))
```

Checkout [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56516958/5678471) answer on Stackoverflow.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is you are trying to do asynchronus in loop which doesn't work the way you are expecting. You need to either use `Promise.all` or use `for..of` loop with await. You can do `Promise.all` way like this.

```
async function singleSearch(q, cx, auth) {
  const res = await customsearch.cse.list({
    "cx": cx,
    "q": q,
    "auth": auth
  });
  return res.data;
}

function search(words, apikey = process.argv[2], engineid = process.argv[3]) {
  const limit = 32; // 32 word limit on google search
  const searchQueries = [];
  const len = Math.ceil(words.length / limit);
  for (var i = 0; i < len; i++) {
    searchQueries.push(words.slice(i * limit, (i + 1) * limit).join(" "));
  }

  return Promise.all(searchQueries.map(query => {
    return singleSearch(query, engineid, apikey).catch(console.error);
  }));
}

(async () => {
  const a = await search("Do I understand it correctly that anotherCall() will be called only when someCall() is completed? What is the most elegant way of calling them in parallel?".split(" "));
  console.log(a);
})();
```